# Anonymous class can be replaced with lambda hint

Tags: android, android-studio, lambda

I use this library to build dialogs: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/

I'm getting this hint

> Anonymous new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() can be replaced with lambda hint.

Since the update to Android Studio 2.4 prev 4, it shows me this issue:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
public void swapConfirm() {
    MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title(R.string.swap_teams)
            .content(R.string.swap_confirm)
            .positiveText(R.string.swap_teams)
            .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    swapTeams("");
                }
            }).build();
    dialog.show();
}
```

How can I change this to the new lambda schema?

I tried the following according to [this blog post](http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html), but it does not work:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says variable `dialog` is already defined in scope change it's name to anything like `dialog1`, for example, and it should work.

This error won't happen if you let Android Studio to convert the anonymous class to lambda for you by clicking `Alt+Enter` and choose the first choice from the intention list.

Comment: Android studio still shows the lambda issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gubb8.png Maybe because it's still in preview

Comment: no it's not android studio inherits this from IntelliJ idea and this is just a hint when lambda is in one line you could delete the curly braces.
the curly braces here is optional